# Prove that if $\,kd\mid d\,$ then $\,k\leqslant1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

In my textbook in the proof for the solving of Diophantine equation of the form $ax + by = c$ they causally used and mention this theorem (I don't know what to call it, sorry if it's not appropriate) without prior talk about it or proof.

"Note that $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime because $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$."

Is it something that you should be able to intuitively see is the case? There is a post about it here ([Prove divisibility with gcd: If $ar+bs=d=\gcd(a,b)$, then $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469692/prove-divisibility-with-gcd-if-arbs-d-gcda-b-then-r-and-s-are-relati)) but the answer there doesn't answer for me how to prove that integer $k$ that divides both $r$ and $s$ must be less than or equal to $1$ because $kd\mid d$.

Is it something along the lines of $\,kd\mid d$

so $\,d=kd\!\cdot\!g\,$ for some integer $g$

and $g$ is either $1$ or $d$, so $k$ is either $1$ or $0$,

but I don't know if that is valid and how to formally state that.

Comment: Your "and g is either 1 or d so k is either 1 or 0" is wrong. Replace it by: $a,b$ are supposed to be $\ne0$ (or at least one of them), so that $d\ne0.$ Hence $kd\mid d$ implies $k\mid1.$ The only integers dividing $1$ are $1$ and $-1.$

Comment: $\,kd\mid d\iff k\mid 1\,$ by cancelling $\,d\neq 0\, $ as in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prove that if $\,kd\mid d\,$ then $\,k\leqslant1$.

**Proof :**

First of all, we have to suppose $\,d\neq0\,,\,$ otherwise the previous property would be false.

Since for hypothesis $\,kd\mid d\,,\,$ there exists an integer $\,g\,$ such that

$d=kd\!\cdot\!g$

and, by dividing by $\,d\neq0\,$ both sides of the previous equality, we get that

$1=k\!\cdot\!g$

hence

$\big(k=1\,\land\,g=1\big)\;$ or $\;\big(k=-1\,\land\,g=-1\big)$

consequently, in any case, it follows that

$k\leqslant1\,.$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque, I apologise for it. I did not know it was a duplicated answer. I am sorry.